# Sqlite ON statement on calculated field failing

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join, string-concatenation, on-clause

I'm trying the following query with no luck:

```
SELECT B.id AS BookId, P.id AS PdfId FROM tbl_Books AS B
INNER JOIN tbl_PDF AS P ON P.FileName = B.ShortName || '.pdf'
COLLATE NOCASE
```

Is in Sqlite possible to use a clause in ON statement?

Thanks

Comment: Works for me. What particular records that you think should match do not?

Comment: I'm trying to match all of the records in the table books with tables pdf. The thing is that I do have a small problem, I need to link the two tables on a field that needs to be calculated.

Comment: As I said, this works for me. Show some example records!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `coalesce(b.ShortName, '.pdf')`. Be aware, though, that it will return empty string if `b.ShortName` is an empty string (as opposed to `null`).

Comment: Why would replacing a missing name with a file extension make sense?

Comment: Not working. If I try "SELECT id, ShortName || '.pdf' AS FileName FROM tbl_Books" then I do get results, and  what is in the result is matching the tbl_PDF.FileName column. Still if I use it in the ON clause is not working.